# Connecting to currently running ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

After creating an agent, it automatically detaches itself from the parent process.

```
someUser@MyPC:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 10222
someUser@MyPC:~$ ps -e --forest | grep ssh-agent
  10222 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
```

When I close the terminal and open a new one to create another agent, there are now two agents running.

```
someUser@MyPC:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 10503
someUser@MyPC:~$ ps -e --forest | grep ssh-agent
  10222 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
  10503 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
```

Is there a command to connect with the existing ssh-agent, as long as a certain controlling terminal doesn't close or kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the `ssh-agent`, it will give you two environment variables: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`. That's why you need the `eval "$(...)"` around the command to start the agent: it outputs the shell commands to set the variables, and `eval` causes those commands to be executed within the current shell session.

To connect with an existing agent, set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable to point to the existing agent's socket. To do that, you could e.g. output the variable and its value to a file after starting it, so other terminals could pick them up from there.

For example:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" > ~/.ssh_auth_sock_info
```

then in another terminal, to pick up the agent connection information:

```
. ~/.ssh_auth_sock_info
```

Likewise, the `SSH_AGENT_PID` variable will contain the PID of the agent, so you can use it in e.g. a logout script to kill the agent.

If you know the agent PID but not the socket path, if you have the necessary privileges to use `lsof`, you could use it to find the socket. For example, in you ran `sudo lsof -p 10222`, you would see the open files and sockets of your first SSH agent. Typically, the file descriptor #3 would be the agent socket.